# Friendlist not complete Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the list of all my friends using facebook graph api. This is my code using python:

```
import facebook 
import json 

def pp(o): 
    print json.dumps(o, indent=1)

g = facebook.GraphAPI('ACCESS_TOKEN')

print
print '---------------'
print 'My Friends'
print '---------------'
pp(g.get_connections('me', 'friends'))
```

But I am not getting complete list of my friends. It shows only 3 friends. What is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're using Graph API v2.0, where the endpoint

```
GET /me/friends
```

only

> returns the user's friends who are also using your app In v2.0, the friends
>   API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using
>   your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends/ for a possible solution.

Comment: even on using v1.0 i am not able to get complete list. I am trying it on access token key of my own profile.

Comment: Did you use Login 2.0? If so, it will behave like Graph API v2.0: "After a person has logged in with v2.0 of Facebook Login, calling /v1.0/me/friends and/v2.0/me/friends` will both result in the v2.0 behaviour - both calls will return the set of the person's friends who also use the app."

Comment: In Graph API explorer v1.0 i can get complete list of all my friends where as in v2.0 i get only friends using that app i.e. Graph API explorer v2.0. So is there any way to get list of all friends of mine ?

Comment: The Graph API Explorer app was created before 4/30/14 so it have access to v1.0. If you app was created after that date your app will not be able to use v1.0. Even if you specify it v2.0 will be used.

Comment: I would be now tougher to increase the reach of the app to other users as now it is not possible to get user's friends and also unlike games we cannot send requests for using apps